# Access XML Data from $File and $XML.Notation.String

Tags: xml, powershell

I'd like to point one variable to a XML File, and another on the path of data to be choosen:

```bsh
[XML]$file = Get-Content XMLfile.xml
$xmlpath = XML.Data.Structure.Data
$data = $file.$xmlpath
```

This does obviously not work.
How can I get what I want? I dont know what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) expressions if you want to do something like that:

```bsh
[xml]$file = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml'
$xpath = '/XML/Data/Structure/Data'
$data = $file.SelectNodes($xpath)
```

Comment: But strange is this does not work in a script. If i put this in a Scriptfile, $data is empty?

Comment: I doubt that. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Ok, i made an error. In the script im using your 3 liner + "write-host $data", which gives a empty line.
Now i dont know how to access the $data object to get the content of the selected xpath.
$data.ToString gives out the last bit of xpath, in your example: "Data" (of /XML/Data/Structure/Data <- This last part)
How can i access the value?

Comment: How about `$data[0].Data`, since `SelectNodes()` returns a collection?

Comment: Ahh, i see. Great. Thanks for the heads up.